# Qlikview chart sorting doesn't always work for users

Tags: sorting, qlikview

I have several Qlikview charts that have interactive sorting enabled but the odd part is some columns can be sorted ascending or descending and others can only be sorted one way.  Nothing happens if you click on the column again.

Each field has a proper sort defined, it looks like a bug - anyone else experience this?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1):

It happens often when on the sort tab of the properties it has selected more than one way of sorting for example you have a field that has sort as text and numeric value

Comment: In this case it was a bug.  If you have disabled fields they need to be at the bottom of the list otherwise it can break sorting.  Known issue with QV.